# Estudante de kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

Estou estudando Kotlin e estou aprendendo sobre construtor, gostaria de saber qual a diferença e quando é usado um construtor primário e um construtor secundário

exemplos:

Init 
Constructor
E definir direto na classe: class House(var cor: String, var vagaGaragem: Int)

se puder explicar de uma maneira simples com exemplos simples me ajuda a entender melhor

obrigado

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma classe no Kotlin pode ter um construtor primário e um ou mais construtores secundários.

No Kotlin é possível criar classes com propriedades usando apenas uma linha de código para isso utiliza-se o construtor primário para declarar as propriedades.

```
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String)
```

Se você precisar executar algum código no construtor primário além de declarar as propriedades, você usa um bloco inicializador utilizando a palavra-chave init.

```
data class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String) {
    init {
        println("Person criado, $firstName $lastName")
    }
}
```

Construtores secundários são usadas para quando você quer instanciar uma mesma classe de diferentes formas.

```
class Person {
    var firstName: String = ""
    var lastName: String = ""

    constructor() {
        firstName = "José"
        lastName = "Silva"
    }

    constructor(name: String) {
        firstName = name
        lastName = "Silva"
    }

    constructor(name: String, last: String) {
        firstName = name
        lastName = last
    }
}

fun main() {
    val person1 = Person()
    val person2 = Person("João")
    val person3 = Person("Marcos", "Santos")

    println("${person1.firstName} ${person1.lastName}")

    println("${person2.firstName} ${person2.lastName}")

    println("${person3.firstName} ${person3.lastName}")
}
```

Caso a classe já tenha um construtor primário, cada construtor secundário precisará delegar ao construtor primário, usando a palavra-chave this.

```
class Person(var firstName: String, var lastName: String) {
    init {
        println("Este bloco será executado primeiro :p")
    }

    constructor() : this("José", "Silva") {
        println("Chamei o construtor primário #1")
    }

    constructor(name: String) : this(name, "Silva") {
        println("Chamei o construtor primário #2")
    }

    constructor(name: String, last: String) : this(name, last) {
        println("Chamei o construtor primário #3")
    }    
}

fun main() {
    val person1 = Person()
    val person2 = Person("João")
    val person3 = Person("Marcos", "Santos")

    println("${person1.firstName} ${person1.lastName}")

    println("${person2.firstName} ${person2.lastName}")

    println("${person3.firstName} ${person3.lastName}")
}
```

Para mais informações aqui tem um link para a documentação do Kotlin sobre classes: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html